# The projective resolution of a direct summand

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

For an $R$-module $M$ fix a projective resolution $P^\bullet\to M$. If $N$ is a direct summand of $M$, that is there is $L$ such that $M=N\oplus L$, then is there a projective resolution of $N$ which is a direct summand of $P^\bullet$ (in the category of complexes)?

Thanks!

Comment: In the Abelian category of complexes, that is not true.  For instance, let $R$ be $\mathbb{Z}$, let $M$ be $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, let $P^\bullet$ be the two-term complex $\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{6\cdot -} \mathbb{Z}$, and let $N$ be $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.  There is a projective resolution $Q^\bullet$ of $N$, $\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{3\cdot -} \mathbb{Z}$.  There is a monomorphism $Q^\bullet\to P^\bullet$, $(1\cdot -, 2\cdot -)$, lifting $N\to M$.  But there is no splitting of this monomorphism in the Abelian category of complexes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; actually I consider this comment as a right answer. Because at the level of the derived category a module is isomorphic to its projective resolution, it is clear that if $N$ is a direct summand of $M$ the same should be true for their projective resolutions. So it seems to me the right question puts at the level of the homotopy category.